# Simple constructor doesn't

Tags: class, kotlin, sftp, jsch

I'm facing a very stupid problem, I know it's probably pretty simple, but I swear it's been two day's since I'm searching...

I'm trying to initialize a jSch class, but every time I try, the constructor doesn't trigger and if I try to use a method after creating the car in my mainActivity, it told me that my object must be initialized.

Here's my class:

```
class SftpClient {

private var jSch: JSch? =null
private var session: Session? = null
private var channelSftp: ChannelSftp? = null
private var connected = false

init {
    createSftp()
}

fun createSftp() {
        try {
            var session: Session
            var jSch = JSch()
            session = jSch.getSession("USER", "IP", 21)
            session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no")
            session.setPassword("PSSW")
            session.connect()

            val channel: Channel = session.openChannel("sftp")
            channel.connect();
            val sftpChannel = channel as ChannelSftp


            sftpChannel.exit()
            session.disconnect()

        } catch (e: JSchException) {
            throw e
        } catch (e: SftpException) {
            throw e
    }
}
}
```

And here my declaration :

```
    var sClient:SftpClient 
    sClient.downloadDir()                  //Here's my error, where "sClient must be initiali
```

Thanks

Comment: What is `SFTPFileTransfer`; I don't see this anywhere in your code. Also, you have declared `sClient` to be of type `SFTPFileTransfer`, but you have not, as the error states, initialised it. Perhaps you want `var sClient = SFTPFileTransfer()`.

Comment: Oh thanks it work I'm so embarrassed haha